# Lebesgue-Stieljes measure and substitution counterexample.

Tags: measure-theory

The goal of this problem is to show that in general, $\int_{(0,\infty)} f(x) d\mu(x) \neq \int_{(\alpha,\infty)} f(x-\alpha) d\mu$.

This was an assumption I made on a math problem which led me to $\int_{(t,\infty)} \frac{1}{x-t} d\mu = \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{x} d\mu$ and ultimately led me astray.

Under which conditions can doing substitution fail?

Comment: I don't think this is true as stated.  Suppose $\mu$ is a point mass at 1.  Then $\int_{(0, t_n)} \frac{1}{x t_n}\,d\mu = 0$ as soon as $t_n < 1$, whereas $\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{x^2}\,d\mu = 1$.

Comment: You're right.  Okay then something was probably off with how I "boiled it down", though I'm not sure what. I've restated the problem above.

Comment: Sorry Nate, I ended up figuring out the problem and I rewrote this question to highlight what the lesson for me was.

Answer (score 1):

This idea comes from Nate Eldredge: Suppose $\mu$ is a point mass of 1 at $\alpha/2$ for $\alpha>0$ and $0$ elsewhere.  This implies that $\int_{(0,\infty)} f(x) d\mu = f(\alpha)$, while $\int_{(\alpha,\infty)} f(x-\alpha) d\mu = 0$.

There is something consistent about the usual Lebesgue measure in that $m((a,b)) = b-a$.  In other words the measure of intervals is not based on their location on the number line, but their width.

Comment: This property is usually called **translation invariance**, and (up to scaling) Lebesgue measure is the only measure that has it.

Comment: Thanks Nate. Or any Stieljes measure with distribution function of the form $ax$ where $a\geq 0$, I think?  $m(k,l) = a(k-l)$.

Comment: Yes, such a measure is precisely $a$ times Lebesgue measure.